# Twitter bootstrap modal sends double ajax request

Tags: ruby, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on rails project as front end developer, and we use twitter bootstrap.. So i have some search modal, and when you type something and hits enter then ajax is called and there are results shown bellow search field..

```
$('#search_term').live("keyup", function(event) {
if (event.keyCode == '13') {
doSearch(this);
}
});
```

and when you hit enter there are 2 ajax calls..

I fixed this by calling die() before live and now it sends only one request, like it should have.. But I do not understand what was the problem?!

```
$('#search_term').die("keyup").live("keyup", function(event) {
if (event.keyCode == '13') {
doSearch(this);
}
});
```

Can anyone explain why this is happen?!

Comment: Maybe the browser is sending `\r\n` and bootstrap treats it as two events?

Answer (score 0):

If with die() you fix the problem likely you are calling the live method more than one time.

```
 $('#search_term').on("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == '13') {
    console.log("ENTER!")
  }
});

$('#search_term').on("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == '13') {
    console.log("ENTER!")
  }
});
```

(Refactored the code because .live it's deprecated)

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcv7d8hd/) and open the developer console. If you press enter inside the input it will call the console.log() multiple times.
In this example you are adding new functions to the keyup event and the result it's that when a keyup is triggered all the functions will be triggered
Instead .die (now it's .off) remove the previous added functions. See this example:

```
 $('#search_term').off("keyup").on("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == '13') {
    console.log("ENTER!")
  }
});

$('#search_term').off("keyup").on("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == '13') {
    console.log("ENTER!")
  }
});
```

Try now this modified [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hwky9j0n/) and see that the function is called only once.